# Windows 7 folder name improve max character length

Tags: windows-7

i want to improve windows 7 folder name character length. default character length is 260. Have you Any suggestion about this problem ?

Comment: How is the 260 character limit a problem? Can you edit your question to let us know more about your situation?

Comment: read here http://superuser.com/a/811155/241386

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to obtain the functionality you are after. the limitation is caused by the $MFT name tables, and cannot be modified.

Comment: The 260 value is MAX_PATH, a Windows architectural limitation, not an NTFS limitation. The NTFS limitation is 255 per folder/directory in the path. The NT kernel limits the total path length to 32,767 characters.

Comment: wrong, you can use `"\\?\"` prefix to access fully qualified name maximum 32767 characters