# Windows 7 file name length limited to 129 characters

Tags: windows-7, filenames

I'm trying to properly name MP3s and I hit some arbitrary length of 129 characters (not 128?). NTFS supports 255 characters in file names, how do I fix this?

> Star Wars - 6 - Return of the Jedi - 2 - 07 - Battle of Endor 2, Leia
>   Is Wounded, The Duel Begins, Overtaking Bunker, Dark Si.mp3

Comment: It is better not to rely on really long filenames as this can lead to a number of problems.  MP3s can have embedded metadata in the form of ID3 tags for this and/or use directories.

Comment: I open files and playlists; I do not use "media libraries". My collections are properly named, I don't have any "1.mp3" files and can't stand people too lazy to properly name files; which "1.mp3" when every album has at least one track. ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible that you are exceeding a total of 260 characters for the entire pathname, including the backslash characters.

How many characters are in the path, including the name of the mp3 file?

Comment: Yeah, turns out renaming the files on the drive without directories allows longer names. Pretty lame that the file name and paths are counted together and not separate.

Comment: the MAX_PATH constant is defined to be 260, not 256

Comment: Folders though, have only a max of "247 char + `<null>`". See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15971467/632951

Comment: You are incorrect re maximum size of a path. It is less than you think.  See https://pastebin.com/raw/Xcg7Wndc and   `C:\t>md "a_243char_ijbcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabhcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghbijabccdghij_243char_hi"` <-- The filename or extension is too long.

Answer (score 37):

In Windows the default total path length must not exceed 260 characters (`drive` + `:\` + `255 characters of filename` + `null terminator` + probably for final `\` in case the path is a directory or simply for even rounding). It was a relic from DOS's 8.3-name era where a 260-character path is a really deep path.

It's possible that your path to the folder was already very long, so the remaining part for your filename is just 129. If you want longer path, you have several solutions:

- use [*fully qualified file names*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file#fully-qualified-vs-relative-paths) with `\\?\` prefix, this way you can use maximum 32767 characters in the path<sup>‡</sup>
- rename the folders in the path to make it shorter
- [mount the folder containing the file](https://serverfault.com/q/11350/343888) into a drive character with [`subst`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst)/[`mountvol`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mountvol)/[`New-PSDrive`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-7.1)/[diskmgmt.msc](https://web.archive.org/web/20160301200730/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/mount-dismount-drive#1TC=windows-7). This way you can use the maximum 255 characters for your file name
- create a [junction](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/)/[symbolic link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/hard-links-and-junctions) to another shallower folder on the path. You can't create links to drive letters, hence you can't achieve filenames as long as if you've used the mounting method

Since Windows 10 there's another option by [removing MAX_PATH limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27680647/995714)<sup>§</sup>. You can enable it by setting `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem LongPathsEnabled` in registry or set *Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem > Enable NTFS long paths* in group policy

Note that folders have a different limit. If you make a new folder in PowerShell or .NET that has very long name you'll get the below error

> The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

That's because it *"allows for 248 characters for the path plus the filename which allows for 12 characters."*

> MAX_PATH, which limits file paths to a paltry 259 characters (sans the terminating null); the current directory to 258 characters (sans a trailing backslash and null); and the path of a new directory to 247 characters (subtract 12 from 259 to leave space for an 8.3 filename).
>
> [The maximum length of the path of a file: 259 or 258 characters?](https://superuser.com/q/1620259/241386)

---

Read more:

- [Why does the 260 character path length limit exist in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1880321/995714)
- [MSDN - Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation)

> <sup>‡</sup>The maximum path of 32,767 characters is approximate, because the `\\?\` prefix may be expanded to a longer string by the system at run time, and this expansion applies to the total length.
>
> <sup>§</sup>Starting in Windows 10, version 1607, `MAX_PATH` limitations have been removed from common Win32 file and directory functions. However, you must opt-in to the new behavior.

Comment: Thanks, David posted first and it worked, but you included resources so +1.

Comment: A similar solution is to use a junction. Check out http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html

Comment: I'd rather use this answer, too. That way, you can keep your files where you want, and still be able to name them the way you'd like to. Plus, when you copy them to your device, it's most likely not going to care about the silly Windows limitation, as they have a very flat file hierarchy, and may not even use the file name directly (e.g. iPhone/iPad/iEtc uses hex characters for file names, and cross-references an index file).

Comment: The maximum number of characters for a filename is 255 characters, not 256

Comment: @Edd 255 characters + null termination

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc no, null termination forms part of the limit on the path, not the filename

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx the more correct way to descbibe it is "the maximum path on drive D is "D:\some 256-character path string<NUL>" where "<NUL>" represents the invisible terminating null character for the current system codepage"

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, Is "`drive`" guaranteed to be only one character long?

Comment: @Pacerier yes. In Windows only 26 drive letters are allowed. If you want to use more than that you must mount under another NTFS folder

Answer (score 0):

If you need to copy the files with long paths.
robocopy does a great job.

Comment: I'm not sure OP needs to copy file, they want to name the file. Do you think robocopy can handle name longer than 255/260?

Comment: Yes I've moved thousands of files & folders with long attached emails saved in them where xcopy constantly failed saying "please reduce filename size" for some reason you can make these long folders & files no problem, one interesting example try to open a pdf from a long path & it will error , but chrome will open it

Answer (score -1):

Windows 7 will allow you to save filenames longer than 256 characters including path names and they can be accessed easily as well.  The only small difficulty you may run into is when you copy them from one place to another, but you will be presented with a popup that asks you if you want to change the filename, not copy the file, or save it as is.  I always save it as is and I've never had any problems.  I've probably got a couple of hundred filenames that exceed the limit.

Comment: no, it won't allow you to save files longer than **255** characters since that's the file system limit

Comment: the path, however, can be slightly longer (or much longer after removing MAX_PATH limitation)