# Does Windows 8 Allow More Symbols for Filenames?

Tags: windows, filenames

I use a lot of question marks and other symbols in naming files with Linux, but Windows 7 doesn't allow these symbols in filenames

> \ / : * ? " < > |

Does Windows 8 or 8.1 allow the naming of files with some or any of these symbols? I searched and searched, but couldn't find a direct answer. TIA

Comment: I really wish we had ":", as it is so often used in titles. One thing you could look into is file explorer \ library programs. Some of them Likely have the ability you seek.

Comment: obviously not, otherwise it'll break all the existing Windows programs. It's only possible with [programs in *POSIX* subsystems for Windows](https://superuser.com/a/1426861/241386) or [programs that bypass Win32 namespace explicitly](https://superuser.com/a/811155/241386)

Answer (score 2):

No. None of the windows operating systems will allow any of these symbols, because they have a special meaning.

Also, windows 8 does not have the ability to use a different character and show it as one of these.