# Convert long file names to short names windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer

Is there a way to convert long file names into a truncated short form on pc? Is there a simple way to do this? I'm new to using the command prompt / PowerShell and don't fully understand what long scripts are doing and how to modify them.

I want to transfer all of my files to an external hard drive but many of the files are from a mac with long names and I receive an error when I try to transfer them.

Comment: Are you talking about using DOS filenames (8+3) or just shorter than they currently are. If so how would a script know what to name a file. You would need rules. Also what are the errors you are getting?, long filenames shouldn't be a problem on Windows 10 unless they are really long.

Comment: I would like to rename them to the DOS filename (8+3). The error I receive when transferring is file name too long. They are really long file names over the Windows limit.

Comment: It's really the [long paths](http://superuser.com/q/811146/241386), not long names because all modern filesystems support filenames of 255 characters. Another possibility is names containing special characters like `*:\/?` which are allowed in POSIX but not in Win32 namespace. So the problem isn't that you need 8.3 DOS names but Windows compatible names

Comment: @ Animatoring, have you finally found a solution for creating 8+3 filenames along with long ones in Windows 10? I don't want to post a similar question. It would be a duplicate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the following into a file `Set-DosFileName.ps1`

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$folder,
    [switch]$recurse
)

$fso = New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject

Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -File -Recurse:$recurse | ForEach-Object {

    $shortName = $fso.getfile($_.Fullname).ShortName
    if ($shortName -ne $_.Name)
    {
        $fullShortName = Join-Path $_.Directory -ChildPath $shortName
        Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.Fullname -Destination $fullShortName
    }
}
```

To use this open a PowerShell window and change into the directory where you saved the file:

```
cd "D:\folder where you saved the script"
```

then:

```
.\Set-DosFileName.ps1 -folder "D:\myfiles\Foo Bar" -whatif
```

The script should show how it would rename your files.

To include all files in subdirectories add the `-recurse` switch:

```
.\Set-DosFileName.ps1 -folder "D:\myfiles\Foo Bar" -whatif -recurse
```

If everything looks fine, remove the `-whatif` switch to actually rename the files. I would still keep a backup of the original files just in case anything goes wrong.

I haven't tested this with a large number of files, be aware that some file names may be pretty ugly.

Comment: Code fails:Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'.

Comment: @ZackA - You must be using a very old version of PowerShell

Comment: I'm using Powershell 7.2.

Comment: In my Powershell 7.2 `Get-ChildItem` has a parameter `-file`, weird.

Answer (score 2):

Since Windows 10 Version 1607, the file path length limit is removed. [To enable this](http://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/), open `regedit.exe`, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem` and create a DOWRD 32Bit `LongPathsEnabled` and change the value to `1`.

[image]

Now the 260 char issue is gone.

Comment: I tried this but I'm not having any luck unfortunately. If you go to rename a long file after doing the changes above it doesn't give the option on my computer. I created a reg_dword for LongPathsEnabled and set it to 1. Did I forget to do something? Thanks!

Comment: ok, the app has to optin via an manifest entry. I haven't checked if explorer has the entry, but I think it should

Comment: Thanks! I noticed I didn't have the most current version that had the ability to enable the long paths. I think it should work now.

Comment: probably he has names with special characters like `?\/*` which are not allowed in Windows

Comment: Really? Does this answer the question "Convert long file names to short names" ??? In fact, it is for the exact opposite: How to create even longer file names by extending their length !!!

Comment: @Apostolos In some cases it is required to first allow long paths before deleting. In my case, the file system does not even provide a short name for the file (Win Server 2016), not sure why.  After enabling the long paths, I am able to delete the file and then switch it back if desired, but really why would I.